# Ideal projection solution for Kinect hack performance

Tags: projector, live-performance

I've been learning about how the Kinect is being hacked by
artists and multi-media nuts to make some incredible interactive
systems. The examples up at [www.kinecthacks.com](http://www.kinecthacks.com) and many other
similar sites.

I'd like to experiment with the kinect for a solo dance performance
piece, where the dancers movements are the input to create live 
projections and sound design.

My question is what kind of projector will I need to be 
suitable for a live performance in a theatre with 100-300 seat
capacity. The projector must be compatible with the Kinect 
motion detector technology, and have sufficient lumens for an
effective live performance, where lighting conditions may vary
slightly.

Any suggestions on how to get a great result out of this
complex A/V setup would be appreciated. If you know of specific
models (with price) that you've evaluated in a similar context, 
that would be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is the same, even with Kinect removed from the equation.  The easiest way to work with a Kinect for custom work is to use it with a PC, so choose the appropriate projector for the room and lighting and then get the hardware to hook the PC up to it.

Specific projector recommendations is likely too specific to the current time and is going to change over time, but you will need a pretty high lumen count if you want to be able to use it in a lit auditorium or at a large projection size (greater than 15 feet or so diagonal).

Answer (score 2):

As AJ Henderson mentioned, you program the Kinect with a PC using various software packages, either ones that support Kinect natively, or by using the Kinect SDK. One that we use often is Derivative TouchDesigner. There is a free educational version you can download and use for non-commercial work.

Projector wise, I'd recommend something of at least 10,000 lumens. Depends where you set up the projector, and how much throw you need. You can use this handy calculator to help you get closer to what you need.

http://www.projectorcentral.com/projection-calculator-pro.cfm